# Change dtype objects of a column(s) in a pandas dataframe to boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, multiple-columns

What I am doing: Using Pandas to analyse a dataset taken from a survey. I have several columns that are Yes or No answers. 
What I want to do and what I want to ask: Change the dtype obj into boolean Yes = True, No = False.
I also want to know if there is a way of doing this for several columns at once.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your categorical data you can use it for multiple columns
Encoding categorical data you will use `LableEncoder` to do encoding as 0,1,2..., according to your 
data but it will generate a new problem and the problem here is that since there 
are different numbers in the same column, the model will misunderstand the 
data to be in some kind of order, 0 < 1 < 2. But this isn’t the case at all. 
To overcome this problem, we use One Hot Encoder.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:,1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:,2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features =  [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```